# How can I update an arraylist from another activity in android studio? Java

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

the activity parts.java has the following arraylist within that i wish to update in the activity loot.java

```
public void inventory(){
    ArrayList<ImageView> inv = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

}
```

loot.java has the following information within the class

```
int commonvalue = random.nextInt(6);
switch(commonvalue){
     case 1:

         Intent i = new Intent(this, parts.class);
         startActivityForResult(i, 100);
     case 2:
     case 3:
     case 4:
     case 5:
}
```

i wish to append a different item to the array within the parts class based on the result from the random in the loot class. There may be several mistakes in my code so i apologise as i am very new to android studio but your help is much appriciated.

Comment: The value of `commonvalue` will never be `5` as `random.nextInt(5)` will return an `int` from `0 to 4`. Also, use `break` with each `case`. Learn more about `switch` from [this chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: okay changed that many thanks

Comment: `int commonvalue = random.nextInt(5)+1` should be used as it will give values between 1 and 5

Comment: is loot an activity?

Comment: yes loot is an activity